# Ubuntu Live USB stuck after booting

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my Windows 8.1 (dualboot). I have created a live USB using Universal USB Installer (and later on also tried Unetbootin, which still failed) and did all the steps here: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

After I disabled fast boot and secure boot options of Windows, I restart, and get BIOS to boot from the USB I created.

Initially it shows the 4 options (try ubuntu, install ubuntu, install OEM , and check disk). Now, selecting either try ubuntu or install ubuntu doesn't do anything for me. The screen just went blank. I tried waiting for more than 10 minutes but still nothing happens.

Has anyone experienced and solved similar problems? My machine is Asus Zenbook.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem last year trying to install ubuntu using a 16GB USB stick. The problem did not occur using a 2GB USB stick so you could try using a smaller size USB stick.